# HD Projector for a home theater?

Tags: projector

I'm looking for a ceiling mounted projector for a home theater. This projector will be used to watch movies, TV and play controller based computer games.

Requirements:

- Long bulb life (my assumption is that the projector will be utilized a couple hours a day on various activities mentioned above)
- Should have vivid colors and not have "streaking" during fast movement in action sequences or games
- 1080p (or higher, if available) resolution
- Multiple device inputs is a plus, preferably with each being HDMI
- Small size. "Small" is subjective, but I don't want a giant object hanging from the ceiling. Smaller should imply lighter.

Some bonus features:

- On/Off and other settings (contrast/brightness/input device/etc) can be configured to utilize a Harmony remote control
- Quick On, less than 10 seconds
- Bulb replacement can be done without removing the entire projector from the ceiling

Most important to me are the first two bullet points.  I've seen and used many projectors that "streak" during fast movement. I want to ensure this does not occur. It would ideally be below $700 and quiet.

Comment: To some extent, streaking is a product of your eyes, rather than the projector. Yes, projectors can reduce the effects, but only to a certain extent - when looking at a bright light, the pigments in your eye that recognise colours get bleached by the bright colours. When the image moves fast, you notice this bleaching as trails left by the moving object. So yes, you can get projectors that have less of this - just be aware that it's unlikely you'll get rid of all of it.

Comment: Do you care about price or fan volume?

Comment: I'd prefer something quiet (home theater and all), price wise, if you can keep the price below $700, I'd be happy. I don't know if that's possible though.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Streaking can also be grouped as a type of ghosting. Ghosting is created from the delay between changing from black to white or vice versa (and things in between) which leaves usually a light gray color streak behind moving things. This can be almost 100% eliminated with better hardware. But then you still have the eye problem you mentioned.

Comment: @Adam aye, that's the improvement you can get in hardware I mentioned. Sadly though, you can't improve your eye hardware.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acer generally has great home theater projectors with tons of positive ratings on both Amazon and Newegg.

The [Acer H6510BD](http://amzn.com/B00B97ZKIA) ($590) has pretty much everything you need.

- Minimum of 4000 hours of lamp life — has eco options to extend this
- 10000:1 contrast ratio to bring out colors and get darker darks
- 1080p resolution supporting screens from 40-300 inches
- Two HDMI inputs plus others — has speakers to utilize HDMI audio if needed
- Only weighs 4.8 pounds, very small compared to others of its caliber
- ±40 degree vertical keystone for mounting on high ceilings
- And of course an array of useful Acer-only features to improve image quality and performance

This seems to be the best buy for the price. I've seen so many other projectors around this price that perform horribly.

Here's [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwTa3zP7O7s) reviewing it against a large wall (80"). You can see vibrant colors and excellent brightness.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the best of the best projector you should use the one I am using now

Xiaomi A300 L1668FCF 4K ALPD WEMAX Ultra Short Throw Proyektor Laser

Okay be careful here because it's a bit confusing.

It's wemax. 4k A300

The price is only around $2k according to https://www.xiaomitoday.com/2021/05/07/xiaomi-wemax-a300-4k-9000-ansi-lumens-projector/

I bought it for $3k

However, the picture is crisp. I think it's the most cost effective projector.

Easily handle 5 m screen due to high lumen. Because 1 m is 40 inch, we're talking about 200 inch display at least. Hei, make it 6m. It'll still be bright enough.

If that's too expensive for you, then use this

Xiaomi Mi Ultra Short 5000 ANSI Lumens Laser Projector

Half the price, only 5k lumen, HD

Is it mounted?

I don't mount it. However, I think you can set it up mounted. The thing is, why?

The reason why you want mounted projector is because you don't want anything to get in the way between projector and the screen right?

In that case, they are Ultra Short Throw.

My A300 needs only a distance of mere half meter to get that 5 m screen.

I think ultra short throw is better than mounted.

I challenge anyone here to show me any better projector at the same price. I've been looking and Xiaomi stuffs are just the plain best for the specs.